# Can't ping IP in LAN

Tags: windows, ip, router, lan

I'm using wifi router and I am not able to ping one laptop (A) from other laptop's in the same network. So basically I can ping from from A to B but not from B to A. A is using Windows and has Ubuntu as dual boot. When I'm on Ubuntu, everything works fine. Also when I'm on Windows, my port forwarding doesn't work as well (works on Ubuntu) but my guess it is related issue.

Labtop A:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 48-5D-60-34-D0-2F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.66(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 20 September 2014 11:43:53
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 21 September 2014 11:43:52
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Laptop B:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1E-65-F7-27-12
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::604b:bc36:9087:b888%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.67(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 20 September 2014 11:43:50
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 21 September 2014 11:43:50
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234888805
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-75-44-40-00-26-22-D7-F5-D7

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I see that laptop B has these rows which are not present in laptop A, can it be that it is somehow related to the issue?

```
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234888805
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-75-44-40-00-26-22-D7-F5-D7
```

One more thing. When I try to ping or access http server on A I always get long waiting rather than 'not available' (and ping gives `time out` rather than `host unreachable`)

Comment: have you set the default router in network settings on windows?

Comment: I didn't set anything. I just pick available wifi and connect to it. Internet is working and I'm able to reach other pcs by IP but they are not (but everything is ok on Ubuntu)

Comment: I have reset my router but it didn't change the behaviour on Windows

Comment: Have you checked firewall settings on both systems?

Comment: yes I've disabled my firewall at all it is still the same.

Comment: And I am able to reach laptop B from laptop C (mobile phone) but not A. so A ->B C->B but not B->A or C->A. And I am able to access http server on A->A by it's IP in the browser